# How to change color of one tick on x axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a multiple points on my x axis so I am trying to plot only every 10000th of them but also add one of the numbers in series which doesn't fall in sequence from limits = c(16995937, 17326059) when I print only each 10000th number. That number which I like to add is 17030090 and I would also like to show that number in red color on x axis.

This is what I tried:

```
  breaks = c(seq(16995937, 17326059, by=10000), 17030090)
  label2 = as.character(breaks)

  a <- ifelse(df$variant == 17030090, "red", "black")

  ggplot(df, aes_string(x="variant",y="value")) +
    geom_point(data=subset(df,label==""),size=1.5) +
    geom_point(data=subset(df,label!=""),col="red",size=1.5) +
    geom_text(aes_string(label="label"),hjust=-0.1,vjust=0.5,size=2.5,col="red") +
    #geom_text(aes_string(label="snp"),hjust=-0.1,vjust=0.5,size=2.5,col="red") +
facet_grid(variable ~ .) +
    #annotation_custom(gtext, xmin=17030090, xmax=17030090, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf)+
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(16995937, 17326059), breaks = breaks, labels = label2) +

    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1,colour = a), legend.position="none") + xlab(paste("Variant position")) + ylab("Posterior probability") +
    ggtitle(ttl)
```

Right now the number which shows in red is 17165934 and I do want 17030090 to be shown in red. The graph I got looks like this:

[image: plot color]
![plot_color][1]

Also instead of showing 17030090 on the x-axis I can just have vertical tick say in red or blue color.

#### UPDATE

I was able to add a tick on x axis on 17030090 location. It would be nice to have an additional annotation (something like on the graph bellow where I have numbers in red boxes) and that in this case the box is blue and has 17030090 inside, maybe with arrow. Or at least a legend showing that that blue color represents 17030090.

This is the new code:

```
  breaks = c(seq(16995937, 17326059, by=10000), 17030090)
  label2 = as.character(breaks)

  ggplot(df, aes_string(x="variant1",y="value")) +
    geom_point(data=subset(df,label==""),size=1.5) +
    geom_point(data=subset(df,label!=""),col="red",size=1.5) +
    geom_label_repel(aes_string(label="label"),hjust=-0.1,vjust=0.5,size=3.5,col="red") +
    facet_grid(variable ~ .) +
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(16995937, 17326059), breaks = breaks, labels = label2) +
    annotation_custom(segmentsGrob(gp = gpar(col = "blue", lwd = 3)), xmin=17030090, xmax=17030090,ymin=-0.01, ymax=0.05) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1), legend.position="none") + xlab(paste("Variant position")) + ylab("Posterior probability") +
    ggtitle(ttl)
```

[image: plot color2]
![plot_color2][1]

Comment: Could you add some data to make your code reproducible?